# how to pluck distinct relations in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

i need to pluck fromcity relation from Route. 
eg

```
 $list = Route::with('fromcity')->get()->pluck('fromcity')->toArray();
```

but it returns duplicate cities from relation. how to get distinct records? Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
$list = Route::with('fromcity')->get()->pluck('fromcity')->unique()->toArray();
```